# Storage common to all users in android 4.2

Tags: android, multi-user, android-4.2-jelly-bean

4.2 Jellybean now supports multiple users.  However as per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers), all calls to all the APIs to get storage location return locations private to the current user (eg: getExternalStorageDirectory()).

I cache plenty of content from servers and store this to external storage, but with a multi user enviornment, this data will need to be duplicated for all users.  This is wasting a lot of space.

Is there any way to store files to a common area for all users to make use of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not, according to the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html):

> No matter which of these APIs you use to save data for a given user,
>   the data will not be accessible while running as a different user.
>   From your app’s point of view, each user is running on a completely
>   separate device.

I hope I'm wrong because I have the same problem as you.

I appreciate that it would have been a potential security hole, but if I saved files in the folder returned by `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`, I would have only myself to blame.